# missing .cs file after deployment in server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

[image]

I have deployed my MVC application in the server and strange, It is looking for the .cs file

I am clueless. Although its an MVC application I am using it as normal asp.net web app.

Comment: What is the Build Action of the file?

Comment: what do you mean by build action? is this debug/release

Comment: build action: highlight the file in Solution Explorer and see the Properties window

Comment: How did you deploy that web-app?

Comment: author.aspx - content author.aspx.cs - compile